# React Native Android Systrace JS marker support

Tags: javascript, android, performance, react-native, systrace

React native Android JS level markers are not nearly as useful as the ones present in IOS (see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0MlT74erp60).

There are couple of things I have observed as of RN 0.29-stable on React native repo on github.

1) Logging into Systrace.js, the _enabled is always false for android(android has code onTraceStarted in Java side but never gets triggered). 
Constrasting with IOS, _enabled is controlled by dev options dialog.

2) Systrace.js uses functions installed globally : nativeTraceBeginSection and others in order for showing markers, which are globally installed for IOS but not for Android. Seeing the corresponding android jni file for jscexecutor,  could probably make use of

```
#ifdef WITH_FBSYSTRACE
#include <fbsystrace.h>
using fbsystrace::FbSystraceSection;
#endif
```

to install global functions to do tracebeginsection and other functions.

Is there any other insight or way to approach for better profiling in android for react-native ?

Seriously all I see is following :
[image]

Comment: same thing as of RN 0.44

Comment: any updates on this?